# An equivalence relation on the space of polynomials in one complex variable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, polynomials, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $P(z)$ be a  polynomial with complex variable $z$.  We consider the following distribution for the roots of  $P(z)=0$: the distribution is a triple $(n_{1},n_{2},n_{3})$
where these integers are the number of roots in the interior of unite circle, on the unit circle and out of unit disc, respectively.

$\ell^{2}$ is the Hilbert space of all square sumable sequence of  complex numbers. $S_1$ is the shift operator on $\ell^{2}.$

**The equivalence relation:** We say two polynomials $P,Q$  are equivalent if $P(S_1)$ is  conjugate to $Q(S_1)$  via  an invertible operator in $B(\ell^{2})$.

Assume that $P,Q$ are two equivalent polynomials:

> 1.Must they have the same degree?
>
> 2.Must they have the same root distribution?

The motivation for the second question is that when $P,Q$ have the same degree and $P$ has $(n_{1},0,n_{3})$ distribution, then $Q$ has the same distribution as $P$. The reason is that $P(S_1)$ is  a  Fredhom operator of index $-n_1$. Obviously this property is invariant under conjucacy. So $Q$ has the same root  distribution.

Comment: If P and Q are equivalent then the spectral mapping theorem gives P(D(0,1))=Q(D(0,1)) and so P(T)=Q(T). So we deduce  P=R(z^k)  S= U ( z^r) where R and U are polynomials with the same number of roots in D.

Comment: @Josep Thanks for the comment. Why $P(T)=Q(T)$?

Comment: @Josep The same argument as yours shows that $P(\mathbb{S}^1)=Q(\mathbb{S}^1)$, the application of spectral mapping to essential spectrum of the shift operator.

Comment: You may apply your observation in the partial case to functions of operators. (For example: $T$ and $T^2$ are not similar since $T-1/2$ and $T^2-1/2$ have different index.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much more is true. According to [the answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/229154/4312) by Alexandre Eremenko (I do not have this paper, but I completely trust him), from $P(\mathbb{S}^1)=Q(\mathbb{S}^1)$ (which are essential spectra of $P(T)$, $Q(T)$ as noted in the comments) it follows that $P=f(z^n)$, $Q=f(wz^m)$ for some number $w$, $|w|=1$, positive integers $n,m$ and polynomial $f$. Further, I claim that $n=m$, it would mean just $Q(z)=P(wz)$. Indeed, choose complex number $a$, $|a|<1$, so that $f(a)\notin P(\mathbb{S}^1)$, and consider polynomials $P(z)-f(a)$, $Q(z)-f(a)$. They do not have roots on $\mathbb{S}^1$, thus the numbers of their roots inside the unit disc must be the same (as noted in your post, these numbers are just Fredholm indices of $P(T)-f(a)$, $Q(t)-f(a)$). But these numbers equal $n\cdot k$, $m\cdot k$ resp., where $k>0$ is the number of roots of $f(z)-f(a)$ in the open unit disc.  Thus $n=m$ as desired.